# How do companies send remote notifications?

Tags: php, ios, swift, push-notification

I'm working on a app for a doctor, that has to receive emergencies from a hospital. Currently I'm sending remote notifications with a php file to a device. To do this have to copy the devicetoken from Xcode and enter it manually in the file.

Now my question is: `How do companies handle so many Devicestoken's and notifications? How to automate this process?`

I thought about saving the devicetoken in a database and then import it in the PHP file and then I have to trigger the PHP file somehow...

edit: realised that sqlite is not the right type of database for this.

Comment: you have to get the device token save it to your database. fire the notification on that device based on your requirement.

Comment: When you register for `push notification ` and it's success you got device token from `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and you have to send this token to server. and according to that token server identify you uniquely and send notification accordingly.

Comment: FYI: push notifications are not guaranteed to get to the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing isn't going to work even for that device because the device token can change -- it's not literally a unique token for the device.

You need to

1. Have the app get the device token
2. Send it over the network to your server along with whatever identifying information about the user you may want to associate with that token
3. Your server script needs to save that information in a database
4. When you want to notify from the server, it can use that database.

Optionally, you could have a way to have a device remove a token (if you have a notion of logging out in the app)

Comment: so i could do this with a database and in the table i would save the token along with a unique id with auto_increment

Comment: Sure. If you want to send the same notifications to everyone all of the time, that would be enough.  If you want to segment based on something, the device needs to send some more information when registering for notifications (dependent on your needs)